# Button on bottom of screen: iPhone X vs regular screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to optimize an app for the iPhone X screen. Currently it shows black or white bars on most screens. As example I will use the `PaymentMethodsView`.

The `PaymentMethodsView` is a custom `UIView` containing 1 or 2 buttons in a horizontal `StackView`, the superView has a gray background. This `StackView` is currently constrained with 16px to the superview (all 4 sides). Currently it looks like this on the iPhone X (and on regular iPhones the view is just on the bottom of the screen:

[image]
What I want to achieve here is that the gray area extends to the bottom of the screen, while the yellow sits where now the bottom of the entire view is. (So 16px lower)

I can get this to work by enabling `Use Safe Area Layout Guide` for this `ViewController`, constraining the `PaymentMethodsView` in the viewController to `0 to safe area` on the sides, and `0 to superview` on bottom. Then in the `PaymentMethodsView` itself, I change all the `StackView`'s constraints to `safe area` instead of `superview`, and change the bottom constraint to 0 instead of 16.
This works fine, except on regular iPhones the bottom 16px (under the StackView) disappears and it puts the yellow button to the bottom of the screen.

How would I go about fixing this?

- On iPhone X: The gray area to the bottom of the screen, the button 0px to the `bottom safe area`
- On regular iPhones: The gray area to the bottom of the screen, 16px between the yellow button and the bottom of the screen.

Thanks!

Comment: If possible, without code but just constraints. :-)

Comment: Check Safe Area Layout Guide bottom length in viewDidLayoutSubviews method and change constraints

Comment: Why did you set the bottom constraint for the `UIStackView` containing the `UIButton` to `0` instead of `16`? That is why the button sticks to the bottom of the screen on previous iPhones, because the "safe area" there just corresponds to the screen edges.

Is there a reason you don't want the button to be 16px from the safe area on an iPhone X?

Comment: The button 16px above the safe area of the iPhone seems to be a lot, the total size of the gray space under the button is then about the same size as the button itself. I kind of agree with you, it should be 16px above the safe area, but at the same time it maybe looks too big.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by adding TWO bottom constraints to your stack view...

First, constrain the grayView Bottom at Zero to the bottom of the view (its superview), ***not*** to the safe-area. Then

- add one constraint from the stackView Bottom to the bottom of the grayView (its superview) at `>= 16`
- and a second constraint from the stackView Bottom to the ***bottom of the safe-area*** at `0` with `Priority: 999`

This says: keep the bottom of the stackView ***at least*** 16-pts from the bottom of its superview (the gray view)

*and*

The `999` says put it at Zero-pts from the bottom of the safe-area *if possible*

[image]

The result on an iPhone 7:

[image]

and on an iPhone XS

[image]

Comment: Really smart! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me give it a try,

1. Click on you view controller
2. Select `Identify and Type` from right panel
3. Under `Interface Builder Document` enable `Use Safe Area Layout`

Now Wherever you want to place any view to bottom just give constraints corresponding to view not safe area